# VScode type hints and autocomplete in js files for Vue and Quasar

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, quasar-framework

I'm currently working on a small webapp using the Quasar UMD
and I would like type hints and auto complete functionality from vscode

I tried using:

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
    "typeAcquisition": {
        "enable": true,
        "include": [
            "vue",
            "quasar"
        ]
    }
}
```

But both `Vue` and `Quasar` are listed as having type any and don't offer any autocompletes.
If I add `"jquery"` to the type acquisition, the `$` global variable works just fine.

Do Vue and Quasar have different names for type acquisition or are other steps required?

Answer (score 0):

you can add required options to `.vscode/settings.json`

Common Configuration:

```
{
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true
}
```

**You can refer to the full list of options in the Quasar Documentation in 'Configure VS Code':**
[https://quasar.dev/start/vs-code-configuration](https://quasar.dev/start/vs-code-configuration#introduction)